# Error Occurred Trusting a SharePoint 2013 Add-in

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-addin

I added a SharePoint 2013 add-in to a site. The app requires that it be trusted. But each time I click "Trust it", I get "An error occurred processing your request".

Please how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realised I was signed in with an account the was "System". I signed in with a non system account(account was also site collection administrator), and that seemed to resolve the issue. Dont seem to know why the system account has the issues.